# C#: How to convert string to Julian date accordingly to the giver format?

Tags: c#, datetime, julian-date

my question is how to convert input DateTime value into Julian date format but the result should be in the format "0YYDDD"? I suppose January, 2nd 2011 should look like "011002".

Thanks

Comment: Just to note, what you are talking about - that is, the day-of-year - is the Julian *date*. The Julian *calendar* is something else: it's an 'earlier version' of the Gregorian calendar generally used now, with the difference that it didn't have the century/four-century leap year rules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2);
Console.WriteLine( String.Format("{0:0yy0dd}",dt) );
```

A good cheatsheet can be found [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: Oh wait, maybe you wanted the total number of days since the beginning of the year? January was not a good example month.

Comment: Yes, I want the total number of days.
If I have 12 December, it should be "010355".

Comment: what is the `0:...` used for?

Comment: I don't know. it doesn't matter. Just requirement from bank.

Comment: @RobertPitt, the 0: refers to the first parameter of the Format function (after the string, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
julianFormatString = "0" + (dateTimeVar.Year % 100).ToString() + "0" + dateTimeVar.Day.ToString();
```